# how to select which id comes second the most often in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like so:

```
create table t1 (
id_a int
id_b int
dt datetime
)
```

Sample data might be:

```
id_a  id_b  dt

39838 6     2014-01-21 11:20:29.537
39838 546   2014-01-21 11:20:29.790
39839 4088  2014-01-21 11:20:31.543
39795 6     2014-01-21 11:20:33.117
39795 546   2014-01-21 11:20:34.100
39795 3189  2014-01-21 11:20:35.520
39841 6     2014-01-21 11:20:36.957
39841 7588  2014-01-21 11:20:38.030
```

I want some SQL that will tell me which id_b follows an id_b of 6 (by follows I mean by dt) for the most id_a

For the sample data above, id_b 546 follow 6 twice for the same id_a and 7588 follows 6 just once for the same id_a, so the output I would be looking for in this case is 546

I hope I've made that clear, can anybody help me with how I'd write sql to do that?

Something to this effect:

```
SELECT most_common(id_b)
FROM t1
WHERE previous_entry(id_b) = 6
  AND previous_entry(id_a) = this_entry(id_a)
ORDER BY id_a, dt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using Parition by clause:

```
SELECT  IB_B, COUNT(ID_A) NO_OF_TIMES FROM
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_A ORDER BY DT) AS ROW_NO
FROM T1)TEMP
WHERE ROW_NO = (SELECT TOP 1 ROW_NO+1 FROM
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_A ORDER BY DT) AS ROW_NO
FROM T1)TEMP
WHERE ib_b =6
)
GROUP BY IB_B ORDER BY COUNT(id_a) DESC
```

Comment: Out of all the answers this has by far the best execution plan on a small data set - not tried it on a large data set

Comment: OK - just tried it on the large data set - 1 second - this one wins out right - thank you

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012, you would do this easily with `lag()`.  The following query gets the counts of everything.  You could add a `top 1` to get the most common:

```
select id_b, count(*) as cnt
from (select t1.*,
             lag(id_b) over (partition by id_a order by dt) as prevb
      from t1
     ) t
where prevb = 6
group by id_b
order by cnt desc;
```

EDIT:

In earlier versions of SQL Server, you don't have `lag()`.  I would just replace it with a correlated subquery:

```
select id_b, count(*) as cnt
from (select t1.*,
             (select top 1 t12.id_b
              from t1 t12
              where t12.id_a = t1.id_a and t12.dt < t1.dt
              order by t12.dt desc
             ) as prevb
      from t1
     ) t
where prevb = 6
group by id_b
order by cnt desc;
```

EDIT II:

If the `6` always begins a new sequence of `id_a`s and doesn't appear anywhere else, you can do:

```
select id_b, count(*) as cnt
from (select max(case when seqnum = 2 then id_b end) as id_b
      from (select t1.*, row_number() over (partition by id_a order by dt) as seqnum
            from t1
           ) t
      group by id_a
      having max(case when seqnum = 1 then id_b end) = 6
     ) t
group by id_b
order by cnt desc;
```

This might produce a better execution plan.

Comment: I'm using 2008 so trying your second query - it is currently running (lot of data).  Will the t12.dt < t1.dt get the next entry or any entry after the 6?

Comment: Adding *WHERE seqnum <= 2* before the *GROUP BY id_a* in the last query might help as it reduces the number of rows processed.

Comment: @dnoeth . . . That is a very good point.  I don't know which of the queries performs best though.

Comment: @Graham . . . In retrospect, that `where` clause is superfluous, so I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

This will also work in SQL Server 2008:

```
WITH cte AS
 ( SELECT id_a, id_b,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dt) AS rn
   FROM t1
 )
SELECT TOP 1 t2.id_b, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM cte AS t1 JOIN cte AS t2
ON t2.rn = t1.rn+1
WHERE t1.id_b = 6
GROUP BY t2.id_b
ORDER BY  COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: This was pretty speedy, but not as fast as AJJs